# How can I get all the documents of a all parent collections asynchronously from firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the documents from all the collections from a firestore database which looks something like this:

```
-users(collection)
    -user1 (document)
        -snippets(collection)
            -snippetdId1 (document)
            -snippetdId2 (document) 
    -user2 (document)
        -snippets (collection)
            -snippetdId1 (document)
            -snippetdId2 (document)
            -snippetdId3 (document)
```

```
let allSnippets = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(async (element) => {
          const snippets = await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(element.id)
            .collection("snippets")
            .get();
          snippets.forEach(
            async (snippet) => await allSnippets.push(snippet.data())
          );
        });
        console.log(allSnippets); // [](length 0, but has all the elements inside)
      });
```

The problem I'm having is that the 'allSnippets' array has a length of 0 but it has all the elements that I want, I know the problem is with synchronicity but I don't know how to solve it.
I've tried using .then instead but is the same thing, length 0 but has all the elements inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `console.log(allSnippets)` runs before any of the `allSnippets.push(snippet.data()` has run. If you add some more logging, or run the code in a debugger, you can easily see this.

Normally, you'd use `Promise.all` to wait until all the `get()` calls for the snippets are done. But here there's actually an easier way. Since you want to get all snippets from all users, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). With that, the entire code is reduced to:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collectionGroup("snippets")
    .get()
    .then((snippetsSnapshot) => {
      const snippets = snippetsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      console.log(snippets);
    })
```